# Reference request: algorithm meta-analyses

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request

Could you direct me to papers that survey families of algorithms? The ideal paper would focus on a single family of algorithms, would show how the improvements in each algorithm work, and ideally would perform this meta-analysis within a single paradigm. [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.20.8270) comes close to this ideal.

Comment: The _Handbook of Satisfiability_ (https://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Satisfiability-Artificial-Intelligence-Applications/dp/1586039296) has a long history and chapters on major satisfiability algorithms. There are a number of survey articles on fast matrix multiplication. For instance, _Fast Matrix Multiplication_ by Mark Blaser. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34173/fast-matrix-multiplication has a number of papers, and Ran Raz has proven lower bounds of $\Omega(n^2 \log n)$ for any matrix multiplication algorithm in _On the Complexity of the Matrix Product_.